# How to insert multiple rows with one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE DATABASE Exercise

USE Exercise;
Go

CREATE TABLE Employees
(
EmployeeNumber nchar(10),
EmployeeName nvarchar(50),
DateHired datetime,
HourlySalary money
);
GO


INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES(N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15),
(N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05);
GO

INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, DateHired)
VALUES(N'Clarice Simms', N'971403', N'20011112');
GO
```

The insert statement is not working.
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Posting code and an error message does not constitute a question on Stack Overflow. This is not a free debugging service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 you cannot use a `,` between `values`:

Replace:

```
INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES(N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15),
(N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05);
```

with a `SELECT` with `UNION ALL` or multiple `INSERT...VALUES...`:

```
INSERT INTO Employees
SELECT N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15 
UNION ALL
SELECT N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05

INSERT INTO Employees
Values(N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15)

INSERT INTO Employees
Values(N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05)
GO

INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, DateHired)
VALUES(N'Clarice Simms', N'971403', N'20011112');
GO
```

So your full script would be:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    EmployeeNumber nchar(10),
    EmployeeName nvarchar(50),
    DateHired datetime,
    HourlySalary money
);
GO


INSERT INTO Employees
select N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15
union all
select N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05
GO

INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, DateHired)
VALUES(N'Clarice Simms', N'971403', N'20011112');
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple insert statements. Instead of

```
INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES(N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15),
(N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05);
```

You could do

```
INSERT INTO Employees
    VALUES (N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15);
INSERT INTO Employees
    VALUES (N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working at SQL Server 2005. It cannot support multivalues insert on 2005. You need to insert it one by one.

```
INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES(N'593705', N'Frank Somah', N'20061004', 26.15)
GO
INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES(N'720947', N'Paul Handsome', N'20000802', 36.05)
GO
INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, DateHired)
VALUES(N'Clarice Simms', N'971403', N'20011112')
GO
```